# Does taking the square root of an inner product guard against numerical instability?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

A colleague of mine told me about a “trick” for guarding against numerical instability in vector computations, and I wanted to check it here.

When I have something like this:

$\frac{xy^T}{x^Ty}$

or perhaps this:

$\frac{xy^T+yx^T}{x^Ty}$

and $x^Ty$ might be extremely small, then I probably want to check the numerical stability of this computation.  So, the “trick” that I was taught was that you can always pre-compute the square root of the thing that you’re worried about being too small. E.g., in this case $x^Ty$.  So, I would compute $\sqrt(x^Ty)$, in this case.  Then, if I do the following substitutions, I can make this division just a multiplication:

$x’ = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^Ty}}$

$y’ = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^Ty}}$

Then the examples above would become

$x’y’^T$

and

$x’y’^T+x’y’^T$

respectively.

Does this protect against the numerical instability here?  And if so, how?   It is supposed to double the decimal place accuracy so you multiply by a larger, more accurate number instead of dividing by a small, possibly inaccurate number.

Comment: Which algorithm is used to evaluate the inner product? Straight application of the definition or do you guard against floating point exceptions?

Comment: I'm just computing `np.sqrt(x.transpose()*y)` using numpy in python.  I'm not sure what the algorithm is....let me research that.  How would one guard against floating point exceptions in that case?

Comment: @CarlChristian is there a particular algorithm for computing the inner product that is best, and do you know if `numpy` implements it that way?